# Apply Where conditionally (OR between them) LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, functional-programming, conditional-statements

I have filters in my asp.net project and want to add expression to this list with condition:

```
Expression<Func<MyModel, bool>> func;
var list = new List<Expression<Func<MyModel, bool>>>();
```

I want to conditionally apply Where (OR between them). for example:

```
if(sth){
   func = p => p.a <= b;
   list.Add(func);
}
if (sth else){
   func = p => p.c >= d;
   list.Add(func);
}

var fq = Session.Query<MyModel>();
fq = list.Aggregate(fq, (current, expression) => current.Where(expression));
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What's wrong with what you have now? You haven't shown the contents of your `MyModel` class (?), but replacing it with, say, `int`, it works.

Comment: edited post, maybe you can help me :( @decPL by the way i'm noob at c#

Comment: Im not getting what you're trying to do??

Comment: Take a look at predicatebuilder http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all, I found the solution : **OrElse**

```
Expression<Func<MyModel, bool>> OrExpressionFunction(Expression<Func<MyModel, bool>> exp1, Expression<Func<MyModel, bool>> exp2)
    {
        ParameterExpression p = exp1.Parameters.Single();
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<MyModel, bool>>(
            Expression.OrElse(exp1.Body, exp2.Body), p);
    }
```

then:

```
Expression<Func<MyModel, bool>> MyExp = null;
if(sth){
  func = p => p.a <= b;
  MyExp= OrExpressionFunction(func, MyExp);
}
if (sth else){
  func = p => p.c >= d;
  MyExp= OrExpressionFunction(func, MyExp);
}
list.Add(MyExp);
```

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you could do this easily with an extension method

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> ConditionalWhere<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, 
                                               bool condition, Func<T,bool> predicate)
    {
        if(!condition)
             return list;
        return list.Where(predicate);
    }
}
```

Usage would be:

```
var fq = Session.Query<MyModel>();
var result = fq.ConditionalWhere(sth, p => p.a <= b)
               .ConditionalWhere(sth_else, p => p.c >= d);
```

Comment: @fsacer - it DOES work, as the OP didnt really want an OR condition, as such - they wanted to conditionally apply a `Where` clause based on a boolean. This just simplifies that a bit (But thatnks for the DV, without even understanding the answer!)

Comment: @fsacer Well question was unclear from the start you have to admit that.

Answer (score 4):

You can build an extension method to merge two condition expressions using `OR` relationship like this:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Or<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> one, Expression<Func<T, bool>> another)
    {
        var parameter = one.Parameters[0];
        var visitor = new ReplaceParameterVisitor(parameter);
        another = (Expression<Func<T, bool>>)visitor.Visit(another);
        var body = Expression.Or(one.Body, another.Body);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, parameter);
    }
}

class ReplaceParameterVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    public ParameterExpression NewParameter { get; private set; }

    public ReplaceParameterVisitor(ParameterExpression newParameter)
    {
        this.NewParameter = newParameter;
    }

    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
    {
        return this.NewParameter;
    }
}
```

Usage and test code:

```
Expression<Func<int, bool>> condition1 = x => x > 8;
Expression<Func<int, bool>> condition2 = y => y < 3;            
var condition = condition1.Or(condition2);
var result = Enumerable
    .Range(1, 10)
    .Where(condition.Compile())
    .ToList();      //1,2,9,10
```

Comment: Well looks like OP doesn't want OR operation, but conditionally apply Where.

Comment: @Cheng This! Dynamically combining conditions with AND is trivial, but OR... And I managed to do something similar but "manually" building expressions like Expression.Equal(Expression.Property... , Expression.Constant...). This is so much more elegant! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I built a bit of code to showcase `Predicate<>` while trying to stick to your program structure:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace SOTests
{
    public class MyModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    class Program
    {
        private static int ControlId;
        private static string ControlName;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var idPred = new Predicate<MyModel>(m => m.Id > ControlId);
            var namePred = new Predicate<MyModel>(m => m.Name == ControlName);

            var list = new List<MyModel>();

            if (true) // TODO: do id check?
            {
                list = list.Where(m => idPred.Invoke(m)).ToList();
            }

            if (true) // TODO: do name check?
            {
                list = list.Where(m => namePred.Invoke(m)).ToList();
            }

            //var fq = Session.Query<MyModel>();
            //fq = list;
        }
    }
}
```

I commented out the `Session` bit not knowing what kind of storage abstraction it represents (and the code wouldn't compile).

The code should explain itself and it's not tested.

It can be much more elegant, but you should state more clearly what your requirements are for that.